# Wordpress: How get link to author page without author ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, author

How get link to default author page without author ID?

I can use `<?php echo get_author_posts_url(''); ?>`

and it give me http: //mysiteadress/?author=0

I need link to http: //mysiteadress/?author without =0

Of course I can use something like this:

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/?author' ) ); ?>
```

... but if someone change in wordpress admin panel Settings->Options permalink, this solution not be flexible...

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The `=0` is the ID of the author. if you have multiple authors it could be `=123` too. So if you remove the ID from the URL Wordpress won't be able to recognize which author do you want to see.

Comment: I know, but maybe exist another function and it give link permanently to http: //mysite address/?author
I looking in wordpress repository but I can't find anything like this